# Change res.getHeader() to res.get()

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript2.0, tsc

I have the following code

```
const compress = require('compression');

export const handleCompression = compress({
  filter: function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    return (/json|text|javascript|css|font|svg/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
  },
  level: 9
});
```

I get this warning from TypeScript:

[image]

Would it be correct to change the call to:

```
res.get('Content-Type')
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes or better: `req.header('Content-Type')`.

See footer [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get).